# trying to Export data in grid to excel in .Net

Tags: .net, excel, vb.net, export, export-to-excel

I am trying to Export data from a grid to Excel in Vb.net

Code as follows:

```
Protected Sub ExportToExcel(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnExpToExcel.Click
    Dim sStringToAppend As String
    Dim sStringToAppend1 As String
    Dim sStringToAppend2 As String
    Dim sStringToAppend3 As String
    Dim strImplicitrate As String
    Dim StrReportFileNAme As String = "[Filename]_" + Session("LoginID") + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".xls"
    If searchFieldRow1.Length <> 1 Then
        sStringToAppend = "<td>" & searchFieldRow1(3) & "</td>"
        sStringToAppend = sStringToAppend + "<td>" & searchFieldRow1(1) & "</td>"
        sStringToAppend = sStringToAppend + "<td>" & searchFieldRow1(2) & "</td>"
    End If
    If searchFieldRow2.Length <> 1 Then
        sStringToAppend = sStringToAppend + "<tr> <td>" & searchFieldRow2(3) & "</td>"
        sStringToAppend = sStringToAppend + "<td>" & searchFieldRow2(1) & "</td>"
        sStringToAppend = sStringToAppend + "<td>" & searchFieldRow2(2) & "</td></tr>"

    End If
    If searchFieldRow3.Length <> 1 Then
        sStringToAppend = sStringToAppend + "<tr> <td>" & searchFieldRow3(3) & "</td>"
        sStringToAppend = sStringToAppend + "<td>" & searchFieldRow3(1) & "</td>"
        sStringToAppend = sStringToAppend + "<td>" & searchFieldRow3(2) & "</td></tr>"

    End If
    If searchFieldRow4.Length <> 1 Then
        sStringToAppend = sStringToAppend + "<tr> <td>" & searchFieldRow4(3) & "</td>"
        sStringToAppend = sStringToAppend + "<td>" & searchFieldRow4(1) & "</td>"
        sStringToAppend = sStringToAppend + "<td>" & searchFieldRow4(2) & "</td></tr>"
    End If

    Try
        Response.Clear()
        Response.Buffer = True
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + StrReportFileNAme + "")
        Response.Charset = ""
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
        Using sw As New StringWriter()
            Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)

            '   To Export all pages
            gvCCRowSearch.AllowSorting = False
            gvCCRowSearch.AllowPaging = False
            Me.fncShowdata(Session("SimulationLatestId"))


            gvCCRowSearch.HeaderRow.ForeColor = Color.Black
            gvCCRowSearch.HeaderRow.Style.Add("height", "40px")
            For Each cell As TableCell In gvCCRowSearch.HeaderRow.Cells
                cell.BackColor = gvCCRowSearch.HeaderStyle.BackColor

                gvCCRowSearch.HeaderRow.Cells.Item(2).ForeColor = Color.Red
                gvCCRowSearch.HeaderRow.Cells.Item(11).ForeColor = Color.Red

                gvCCRowSearch.HeaderRow.Cells.Item(7).BackColor = Color.LightBlue
                gvCCRowSearch.HeaderRow.Cells.Item(8).BackColor = Color.LightBlue
                gvCCRowSearch.HeaderRow.Cells.Item(9).BackColor = Color.LightBlue

                gvCCRowSearch.HeaderRow.Cells.Item(10).BackColor = Color.LightPink
                gvCCRowSearch.HeaderRow.Cells.Item(11).BackColor = Color.LightPink
                gvCCRowSearch.HeaderRow.Cells.Item(12).BackColor = Color.LightPink
                gvCCRowSearch.HeaderRow.Cells.Item(13).BackColor = Color.LightPink
                gvCCRowSearch.HeaderRow.Cells.Item(14).BackColor = Color.LightPink
                gvCCRowSearch.HeaderRow.Cells.Item(15).BackColor = Color.LightPink

                gvCCRowSearch.HeaderRow.Cells.Item(16).BackColor = Color.LightBlue
                gvCCRowSearch.HeaderRow.Cells.Item(17).BackColor = Color.LightBlue
                gvCCRowSearch.HeaderRow.Cells.Item(18).BackColor = Color.LightBlue
                gvCCRowSearch.HeaderRow.Cells.Item(19).BackColor = Color.LightBlue
                gvCCRowSearch.HeaderRow.Cells.Item(20).BackColor = Color.LightBlue
                gvCCRowSearch.HeaderRow.Cells.Item(21).BackColor = Color.LightBlue
                gvCCRowSearch.HeaderRow.Cells.Item(22).BackColor = Color.LightBlue
                '   gvCCRowSearch.HeaderRow.Cells.Item(22).BackColor = Color.LightBlue
            Next

            For Each row As GridViewRow In gvCCRowSearch.Rows
                '  row.BackColor = Color.Orange
                For Each cell As TableCell In row.Cells
                    row.Cells.Item(3).BackColor = Color.Orange
                    row.Cells.Item(4).BackColor = Color.Orange
                    row.Cells.Item(5).BackColor = Color.Orange
                    row.Cells.Item(6).BackColor = Color.Orange
                    row.Cells.Item(7).BackColor = Color.Orange
                    row.Cells.Item(8).BackColor = Color.Orange
                    row.Cells.Item(9).BackColor = Color.Orange
                    row.Cells.Item(10).BackColor = Color.Orange
                    row.Cells.Item(11).BackColor = Color.Orange
                    row.Cells.Item(12).BackColor = Color.Orange
                    row.Cells.Item(13).BackColor = Color.Orange
                    row.Cells.Item(14).BackColor = Color.Orange
                    row.Cells.Item(15).BackColor = Color.Orange
                    row.Cells.Item(16).BackColor = Color.Orange
                    row.Cells.Item(17).BackColor = Color.Orange
                    row.Cells.Item(18).BackColor = Color.Orange
                    row.Cells.Item(19).BackColor = Color.Orange
                    row.Cells.Item(20).BackColor = Color.Orange
                    row.Cells.Item(21).BackColor = Color.Orange
                    row.Cells.Item(22).BackColor = Color.Orange
                    'If row.RowIndex Mod 2 = 0 Then
                    '    cell.BackColor = gvCCRowSearch.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor
                    'Else
                    '    cell.BackColor = gvCCRowSearch.RowStyle.BackColor
                    'End If
                    cell.CssClass = "textmode"
                    Dim controls As New List(Of Control)()

                    ' Add controls to be removed to Generic List
                    For Each control As Control In cell.Controls
                        controls.Add(control)
                    Next

                    ' Loop through the controls to be removed And replace then with Literal
                    For Each control As Control In controls
                        Select Case control.GetType().Name
                            Case "HyperLink"
                                cell.Controls.Add(New Literal() With {
                                 .Text = TryCast(control, HyperLink).Text
                                })
                                Exit Select
                            Case "TextBox"
                                cell.Controls.Add(New Literal() With {
                                 .Text = TryCast(control, TextBox).Text
                                })
                                Exit Select
                            Case "LinkButton"
                                cell.Controls.Add(New Literal() With {
                                 .Text = TryCast(control, LinkButton).Text
                                })
                                Exit Select
                            Case "CheckBox"
                                cell.Controls.Add(New Literal() With {
                                 .Text = TryCast(control, CheckBox).Text
                                })
                                Exit Select
                            Case "DropDownList"
                                cell.Controls.Add(New Literal() With {
                                 .Text = TryCast(control, DropDownList).SelectedValue
                                })
                                Exit Select
                            Case "RadioButton"
                                cell.Controls.Add(New Literal() With {
                                 .Text = TryCast(control, RadioButton).Text
                                })
                                Exit Select
                        End Select
                        cell.Controls.Remove(control)

                    Next
                Next
            Next
            ' gvSearchResult.ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData = True

            gvCCRowSearch.RenderControl(hw)

            ' style to format numbers to string
            Dim style As String = "<style> .textmode {} </style>"
            If sStringToAppend = "" Then
                style = style & "<table><tr><td style='bgcolor=#d3d3d3;width=550px;'><b>Lease Accounting Database</b>  as on :</td><td>" & Format(Date.Now, "dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm") & " </td></tr>" &
              "<tr><td></td></tr><tr><td><b>Vendor Code:</b></td> <td>" & strVendorCode & "</td> </tr><tr><td><b>Entiry:</b></td><td>" & StrEntity & "</td></tr> <tr><td><b>Lessor Name:</b></td><td>" & StrLessorName & "</td></tr> <tr><td><b>Description of Asset:</b></td><td>" & StrAssetDesc & "</td></tr>  <tr><td><b>Country:</b></td><td>" & strCountry & "</td></tr>  <tr><td><b>Station:</b></td><td>" & strSation & "</td></tr> <tr><td><b>Implicit Rate:</b></td><td>" & strImplicitrate & "</td></tr> <tr><td></td></tr>  " &
              " </table>"
            Else
                style = style & "<table><tr><td style='bgcolor=#d3d3d3;width=550px;'><b>Price Incoice and Control Tool</b>  as on :</td><td>" & Format(Date.Now, "dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm") & " </td></tr> " &
                            "<tr><td></td></tr><tr><td><b>Vendor Code:</b></td> <td>" & strVendorCode & "</td> </tr><tr><td><b>Entiry:</b></td><td>" & StrEntity & "</td></tr> <tr><td><b>Lessor Name:</b></td><td>" & StrLessorName & "</td></tr> <tr><td><b>Description of Asset:</b></td><td>" & StrAssetDesc & "</td></tr>  <tr><td><b>Country:</b></td><td>" & strCountry & "</td></tr>  <tr><td><b>Station:</b></td><td>" & strSation & "</td></tr> <tr><td><b>Implicit Rate:</b></td><td>" & strImplicitrate & "</td></tr> <tr><td></td></tr>  " &
                            "<tr>" & sStringToAppend & "</tr><tr></td></td></tr> </table>"
            End If
            Response.Write(style)
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString())
            Response.Flush()
            Response.End()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        ex.Message().ToString()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Now when open the file in excel I am getting the following error.
Error says on Excel File as follows:

The file Format and extension of [FileName].xls dont match.The file could be courpted or unsafe.Unless you trust or  corrupted  or unsafe.Unless you trust its source,Dont open it .Do you want to open it anyways...

And Then show me button with name Yes/no/help

Comment: It's quite strange that you write HTMLand want it to be opened by Excel. Probably it's the reason of issue

Comment: Because you're creating a html document and saving it as a .xls file - adding that extension doesn't make it an Excel file, and so when you open it Excel (quite rightly) states that it's not the correct file format. Your best bet here is to write to something more generic like a csv and import that into Excel instead.